# Hook method to various boxes whenever one of the text box changes text, is there a simple way?

Tags: c#, winforms, hook

I wanna keep my program information updated, so I've been using the same method over and over again in each of these text changed method

```
private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { //specific code for textBox5
      updatedatamethod(); }

private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { //specific code for textBox6
      updatedatamethod(); }

private void textBox7_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { //specific code for textBox7
      updatedatamethod(); }

private void textBox8_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { //specific code for textBox8
      updatedatamethod(); }
```

etc...

I have the feeling this is a very crude way to program, since I'm not a native programmer I'm wondering if there's a technical more simple way to do it.

Note that I don't want all the text boxes to do the updatedatamethod, but only some of them

Edit: working on winforms

Edit2: some users marked this as a duplicate and posted a link, I understand it, but I don't agree. I don't wanna do only the `updatedatamethod` i posted on my example, I also wanna do other specific button code besides that. The answer linked as a duplicate, assumes you wanna do the exactly same thing and nothing else on every item.

Comment: If all you need is to make sure some string property is always updated, check out databinding.

Comment: What kind of application are you targeting ? Winform, WPF etc ?

Comment: In the Visual Studio GUI Designer, instead of double clicking the event in the properties window, click on the arrow next to it. You'll see a list of methods you can attach to it. Just attach the same one to all textboxes.

Comment: Wow so many new stuff, thanks guys I'll take a look and then reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest would be to attach a single event handler to all the textboxes' `Click` event like:

```
textBox5.Click +=textBox_TextChanged;
textBox6.Click +=textBox_TextChanged;
textBox7.Click +=textBox_TextChanged;
```

in that event handler you can do:

EDIT: If you want to do some specific task related to each `TextBox`, then you can cast the sender as `TextBox` and compare it against your TextBoxes. like:

```
void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (textBox == null)
    {
        return;//log or show message 
    }

    if (textBox == textBox5)
    {
        //Specific for TextBox5
    }
    if (textBox == textBox6)
    {
        //Specific for TextBox6
    }
    updatedatamethod();
}
```

You can do that in the constructor after initializing your controls.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't fully answer either. Can I add several actions? For example: `textBox5.TextChanged +=method1; textBox5.TextChanged +=method2;`  I'm hoping that this way, it would do method1 AND method2, because I have other specific code to each textBox. (I updated the question) @Habib

Comment: @ng80092b, I have edited my answer in response to your edit. Hope this helps.